# JavaScript frameworks and web development

Tags: javascript-framework

I am a beginner in javascript.I started fixing some bugs in JavaScript and started digging to learn more.

In my application , there is an applet which displays dynamic info. We try to display a network graph  (imagine something like GoogleMap ) .

Now the problem statement is ,

1. If i want to achieve rich advanced UI features and decide to throw away the applet code, which javascript framework i shud go for ?
2. It s a dynamic data we try to display , so what do you recommend for a very rich GUI development ?

I am a novice to web development and have no idea of the technologies involved and there usage.

So please do let me know your suggestions in detail.

regards

Answer (score -1):

Everyone needs to know [jQuery](http://www.jquery.org) and its plugins.

Comment: Thanks for that , but could you let me know whether iwillbe able to model objects in javascript without using SVG ???